# PHP: Get entire JSON from a URL and print as JSON inside another php page?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I'm trying to get a `JSON from a URL` and print it all as JSON again inside `another PHP page`.

for this I'm using this code:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
//header('Content-type: application/json');
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");


$json = file_get_contents('https://www.some-domain.com/jsonpage.php');

$obj = json_decode($json);

//print_r($obj);

echo json_encode($obj);
```

This will get the URL content and prints it all inside my PHP page but when I try to use the JSON data via `jquery AJAX jsonp`, I get nothing in response.

I know my jquery code works fine because when I use it with another json data that I created (**not from the URL**), it works just fine!

This is my jquery code if it helps:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'https://XXXXXXXXX.net/json.php',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){

            $.each(data, function(pi,item){ 
            str = item.id;  
            alert('hello');

                var products = '<div id="'+item.id+'" class="items">'+
                               '<p class="names">'+item.title+'</p>'+
                               '</div>';
                poutput.append(products);


});


},

        error: function(){
            //alert('There was an error loading the data.');

        }


});
```

As a test, i went ahead and tried to get only values of `title` from URL and print them inside my PHP page and this worked fine too...

I used this code:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://www.some-domain.com/jsonpage.php');

$array = json_decode($json);

$urlPoster=array();
foreach ($array as $value) { 
    $urlPoster[]=$value->title;
}

print_r($urlPoster);
```

and the code above printed this on my page:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Title 1
    [1] => Title 2
    [2] => Title 3
    [3] => Title 4
    [4] => Title 5
    [5] => Title 6

)
```

Could someone please advise on how to get all the json data from URL and print them all inside another PHP file as json data again so they can be used in jquery AJAX.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Json` and `Jsonp` are two different, but related things.

to use json modify your javascript... (json is default for jQuery)

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://XXXXXXXXX.net/json.php',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status){
    }
 });
```

to use jsonP with your existing javascript, modify your server code...

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Content-type: application/javascript');
//header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

$json = file_get_contents('https://www.some-domain.com/jsonpage.php');

$obj = json_decode($json);

//print_r($obj);

echo 'jsoncallback(' . json_encode($obj) . ');';
```

In jsonp note the `jsoncallback()` wrapper arround your json data. `jsoncallback` is the same as the value you put in jsonp in your ajax call. You also need to change the returned header to `application/javascript`

additional reading for using jsonp with jQuery

https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/